# Sharepoint 2010 PeoplePicker is not showing the drop down with name choices when there are more than one match

Tags: sharepoint-2010, peoplepicker

Scenario:  People Picker control on an aspx page.

```
<wssawc:PeopleEditor AllowEmpty="false" AcceptAnyEmailAddresses="true" ValidateResolvedEntity="true"
    ShowButtons="true" ShowDataValidationErrorBorder="true" ShowEntityDisplayTextInTextBox="true"
    ShowErrorPlaceHolder="true" ValidatorEnabled="true" MultiSelect="false" ID="secondaryOwnerPicker"
    runat="server" SelectionSet="User" Width="40em" AllowTypeIn="true" DoPostBackOnResolve="false"
    EnableBrowse="true" ForceClaims="true" Title="Secondary Owner People Picker" UrlZone="Extranet"
    EnabledClaimProviders="ADClaimsProvider" />
```

the user types in a name that has multiple matches and there is no list box that pops up when you mouse over the name to resolve it as you would do in SP2010 Central Admin.  the message i get when i mouse over the name with the red underline is "mulitple entries match, please resolve".  nothing happens when i click on the red underlined name.

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE** I see this javascript error after trying to click the name to resolve multiple matches:

> Error: CAMOpt is not defined
>   Source file: http://myServer/_layouts/entityeditor.js?rev=1%2Fj%2Ba5PO0xZXnRjXxVHOkg%3D%3D
>   Line: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i already had webcontrols registered but needed to add a reference to the core.js file

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssawc" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

in the head add

```
<wssawc:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" Language="javascript" Name="core.js" runat="server" />
```

include these two styles for the nice box with all the names found

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/layouts.css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/Themable/corev4.css" />
```